Unit test performs better when started from ReSharper Test Session?
I have a unit test including a stopwatch measuring the execution time of certain .NET library calls.
I get significantly shorter execution times when I start the unit test from ReSharper Test Session in contrast with starting the exact same test from Visual Studio Test Explorer. By significantly I mean half, execution time when started from ReSharper is half the execution time when started from VS Test Explorer.
My question is → what's causing the difference?
ReSharper:

0003: 406 ms - EXPR
0002: 359 ms - MSIL
0001: 297 ms - Typed

VS Test Explorer:

0003: 781 ms - EXPR
0002: 688 ms - MSIL
0001: 641 ms - Typed

Everything is compiled in Release mode
The measured code is not implemented in the unit test, the test only invokes the measure functions from a compiled assembly
I created a console application executing the same test → measured execution times are similar to VS Test Explorer.
What does ReSharper Test Session runner do to achieve better performance than a regular .NET console application?

I am the author of the ReSharper test runner and I have no idea. :)
First of all, our test runner (as well as VS's) covers a multitude of scenarios. Them being different runtimes (.NETFramework | .NETCore | Mono), different target frameworks, different test frameworks. To know where to look I would first need to know your setup.
But the statement that the calls work faster from our runner than from a plain console app is really bizarre. The only thing that comes to mind right now is that we enable server garbage collection mode by default for .NETFramework.

Thank you Eugene, this is a very great insight from the very best source. Sorry, I forgot to mention, runtime is .NETFramework indeed. So, the server garbage collection flavor might have something to do with it, I'm measuring the deep cloning of huge object trees. I'll give it try in my console app and let you know.

My console app tests confirmed your suspicion. Performance difference is caused by server garbage collection mode.
